# Mudar de form em forms

Tags: c#

Bom dia,
Eu gostaria de saber como posso mudar de formulario para outro formulario em c#, eu tentei porém ficam tanto o antigo como o novo a aparecer.

```
new form1().Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia os meus dias de c# já lá vão mas penso que esta seja a resposta:

```
new nomedonovoforms().Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: Consegui Agradeço